# Reboot on Grub Selection

Tags: grub2

Installed Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit on X79-UD5 motherboard (8x4Gb Ram, on 120Gb SSD) with GTX580 gfx card. Had to do nomodeset, otherwise the installer would hang during intialisation or not load at all. After completing the installation, Ubuntu restarts and loads grub menu. Either selection in the grub causes the system to immediately restart and goes back to grub.

Any idea what's causing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

(*Edit question and provided answer from OP*)

I initially installed with network connectivity and it downloaded updates. I re-installed and shut off network connection during installation and I no longer have issue. However, I'm worried that when I update I'll run into an error again. Will edit this post after update if same error re-occurs.